# Unable to use if else condition properly in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Nodejs and using "express js",Right now i am getting list of users (in console.log) and now i want to pass this data to "model" but in console.log showing me "undefined",How can i solve this ?
Here is my controller code

```
const sendotps = async (req, res) => {
    var phone_number=req.body.phone_number;
    const result= await User.sendOtp(phone_number);
    console.log(result); // GETTING UNDEFINED HERE
}

Here is my model file

 

    static sendOtp(phone_number) {
            var otp=Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9999);
            
            var config = {
            method: 'get',
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
              url: 'http://2factor.in/API/V1/xxxxxxxx/SMS/+xxxxxxx/'+otp+'/XXXXXXXX',
              headers: { }
            };
             return axios(config)
            .then(async function (response) {
                
                const sql = "SELECT phoneNumber FROM verifyOtp WHERE phoneNumber = '${phone_number}'";
                const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql);
                if(rows>0)
                {
                    console.log('total rows are more than zero'+ rows);
                }
                else
                {
                    const sql = `INSERT INTO verifyOtp (phoneNumber, otp, userType) VALUES ("${phone_number}", "${otp}", "2")`;
                    await pool.execute(sql);
    const sql2 = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone_number = '${phone_number}' AND is_registered='1'`;
                    const [rows2, fields2] = await pool.execute(sql2);
                    console.log(rows2);
                   if(rows2>0)
                    {
                            return rows2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            return false;
                    }
    
    
                }   
    
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
              
            });
            
        }
```

Comment: You need to return a promise object from the sendOtp function. I think you are not returning promise from Models sendOtp function.

Comment: @MohammadAslam Sir, can you post your answer so i can check at my side

Comment: without seeing the code for `User.sendOtp` this is impossible to answer

Comment: @RobinZigmond let me update my question (full code)

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the axios call as well. The return in then block returns data to the axios call, But you need to return that data back to the function call.

Comment: Agarwal can you post your code so i can check

Comment: return axios(config)
    .then(async function(response) {
            const sql2 = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone_number = '${phone_number}' AND is_registered='1'`;
            const [rows2, fields2] = await pool.execute(sql2);
            console.log(rows2); //GETTING DATA IN CONSOLE
            if (rows2 > 0) {
                return rows2;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

Comment: Agarwal still getting same error

Comment: can you share the code for User.sendOtp(phone_number)

Comment: Agarwal let me update(explain) my code

Comment: Hi, please do not include relevant code in comments. Instead, edit your answer and paste all code inside